# SOAP communication over TLS instead of SSL3.0

Tags: php, web-services, soap, afas-online

I'm using SOAP to communicate with a webservice of AFAS. Since it's known that SSL 3.0 protocol has some security issues, they have stopped supporting this protocol. **They now only support TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.** My PHP SOAP script has now crashed and gives me this error:

> `Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR:
>   Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl'
>   : failed to load external entity
>   "https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl"`

At the moment I don't know where I have to fix this issue. How would I communicate over a different protocol? Do I need to change something in the PHP Code or is this a server issue?

Below the php code I'm using, further down some server information:

```
$wsdl = "https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/updateconnector.asmx?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClientAuth($wsdl,
    array(
        'login' => $login,
        'password' => $password
    ));
```

SoapClientAuth class:

```
class SoapClientAuth extends SoapClient{
  public $Username = NULL;
  public $Password = NULL;

  /**
   *
   * @param string $wsdl
   * @param array $options
   */
  function SoapClientAuth($wsdl, $options = NULL)
  {
    stream_wrapper_unregister('https');
    stream_wrapper_unregister('http');
    stream_wrapper_register('https', 'streamWrapperHttpAuth');
    stream_wrapper_register('http', 'streamWrapperHttpAuth');

    if($options)
    {
      $this->Username = $options['login'];
      streamWrapperHttpAuth::$Username = $this->Username;
      $this->Password = $options['password'];
      streamWrapperHttpAuth::$Password = $this->Password;
    }

    #parent::SoapClient($wsdl, ($options?$options:array()));
    parent::SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

    stream_wrapper_restore('https');
    stream_wrapper_restore('http');
  }
```

Server information:

```
Registered PHP Streams: https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports: tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
SSL Version: OpenSSL/1.0.0
```

**UPDATE**
I updated my first part of code after reading [this article](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Transport-Layer-Security-(HTTPS-SSL-and-TLS).html), also not succes :( :

```
$opts = array(
  'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'cafile'        => '/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem',
    'verify_depth'  => 5,
    'CN_match'      => 'profitweb.afasonline.nl',
    'disable_compression' => true,
    'SNI_enabled'         => true,
    'ciphers'             => 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK'
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$client = new SoapClientAuth($wsdl,
  array(
    'login' => $login,
    'password' => $password,
    'stream_context' => $context,
  ));
```

I also dit a [SSL test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) and this tels mee that TLS 1.0 is supported by the server (1.1 and 1.2 not).

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that the default SOAP client in php does not support authentication FOR THE WSDL ITSELF.  Yes this is poor, but you can either download the wsdl and load it from disk each time (not recommended, but is a good cheap fix) or look at other options of fetching the wsdl dynamically, perhaps using curl.